# About Door Anatomy. Is it called a door frame or a casing?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> **[casin](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/casing)g**
>
> 2 : a frame around a door or window

---

> **[door](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/door)**
>
> a : a movable piece of wood, glass, or metal that swings or slides
>   open and shut so that people can enter or leave a room, building,
>   vehicle, etc.

---

Look at this pcture

[image]

**Is it  called a door frame or a casing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a door frame.

I am a native English speaker, and I have never heard anyone refer to it as a 'casing'.

Many people would refer to it as the 'door jamb' too, although the jamb might, technically, be the part that the hinge is fixed to (I am not a carpenter, nor a builder, so I might be wrong about that).

Alan.

Comment: Yes, never a ‘casing’, usually a ‘frame’, but sometimes a ‘jamb’.  Technically the ‘jamb’ is just the vertical part of the frame, but people often extend that meaning to the whole frame (for example, some YouTube videos describing how to install door frames).